# Positioning text within an image in HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to produce a responsive grid using HTML and CSS.  What I'm trying to achieve is to get the text that says 'Top left' within the image, as per https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp, whilst maintaining the responsive look of the grid, and it's not doing this currently.  My HTML code is as follows:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700');

/* Design */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: #ecf9ff;
}

body {
  color: #272727;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.main{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: transparent;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cards_item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 56rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card_content {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #EF8D9C 40%, #FFC39E 100%);
}

.card_title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0px;
}

.card_text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;    
  font-weight: 400;
}
.made_by{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  
.image_wrapper {
    position: relative;
}  
  
.top_left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <h1>Responsive Card Grid Layout</h1>
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="cards_item">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="image_wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=10"><p class="top_left">Top Left</p></div>
        <div class="card_content">
          <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
        <p class="card_text">Some text</p>
        <p class="card_text">Some more text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="cards_item">
      <div class="card">
        <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=5"></div>
        <div class="card_content">
          <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
          <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="cards_item">
      <div class="card">
        <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=11"></div>
        <div class="card_content">
          <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
          <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="cards_item">
      <div class="card">
        <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=14"></div>
        <div class="card_content">
          <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
          <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
          <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would someone help me, please?

Comment: It seems to be working properly when I try, can you further explain what the problem is?

Comment: The issue is I'd like the 'Top Left' text to be within the image, it comes out as being below the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```html
<head>
  <style>
  /* Font */
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700');
  /* Design */
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  html {
  background-color: #ecf9ff;
  }
  body {
  color: #272727;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  }
  .main{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  }
  img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: transparent;
  }
  .btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  }
  .cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
  .cards_item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  }
  @media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .cards_item {
  width: 50%;
  }
  }
  @media (min-width: 56rem) {
  .cards_item {
  width: 33.3333%;
  }
  }
  .card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  }
  .card_content {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #EF8D9C 40%, #FFC39E 100%);
  }
  .card_title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0px;
  }
  .card_text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  }
  .made_by{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  }
  .top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Responsive Card Grid Layout</h1>
    <ul class="cards">
      <li class="cards_item">
        <div class="card">
          <div </div>
          <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=10"><p class="top-left">Top Left</p></div>
          <div class="card_content">
            <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
            <p class="card_text">Some text</p>
            <p class="card_text">Some more text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="cards_item">
        <div class="card">
          <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=5"></div>
          <div class="card_content">
            <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
            <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="cards_item">
        <div class="card">
          <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=11"></div>
          <div class="card_content">
            <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
            <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="cards_item">
        <div class="card">
          <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=14"></div>
          <div class="card_content">
            <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
            <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
            <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

do one thing make that image wrapper div property set to relative. then make ur top-left class to position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px

Comment: .top-left{position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0px;}

Comment: img wrapper div style like div{ position: relative }

Comment: .top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
  }
  } css closing tag issue in ur style

Comment: I've altered the HTML In the question above, and it's still doing the same thing, the text is below the image, when that's not what I want, I'd like it to be within the image.

Comment: I've also tried altering the CSS for .top_left to .top_left {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; color: #fff; padding: 20px; margin: 0px;} and it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: please check my below code . it will solve your issue. thank you